# Cannot import from Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, import

I want to evaluate my model in DeepLabCut, using the function : ***deeplabcut.evaluate_network(path_config_file,plotting=True)***

But, I keep having this problem when runing the code:
***No module named 'keras.legacy_tf_layers'***

I don't want to change the TF version as I am using the GPU and the current version which is (*2.10.0*) more adequate.

The current version of Keras is the same (*2.10.0*).

Can somebody help ?

I tried importing the module,
***from keras import legacy_tf_layers***
***from tensorflow.keras import legacy_tf_layers***

but it didn't work,
***cannot import name 'legacy_tf_layers' from 'keras'***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are following old document for coding with latest tensorflow and keras versions which is showing this error.

You can import [layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers) using below code in `Tensorflow 2.x:`

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end, I just restarted all the installation. It was a problem of compatibility I reckon.

Comment: Hi @Rimee, Yes The document you are following has used old APIs which leads to error when running it with latest installed TF version where API structure has changed. Could you upvote and accept the answer if it helped you? Thank you. Happy Coding!